# Prove $|(0,1)| = |(a,b)|$

Tags: functions, cardinals

I'm kinda confused how to prove it.

Information given : $a,b$ are real numbers such that $a<b$.

$(0,1)$ is interval (without $0$ and $1$) and $(a,b)$ is also interval without $a$ and $b$.

I had Idea of making one-to-one function as we do in $(0,1)$ to $(1,3)$ but I don't think that's the case, any ideas ?

Comment: How might you rescale the identity map on $(0,1)$ to be a bijection $(0,1)\to (a,b)$?

Comment: "I had Idea of making one-to-one function as we do in (0,1) to (1,3) but I don't think that's the case, any Ideas ?" -- How did you find the function from (0,1) to (1,3), and why don't you think the same method would work here?

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

> I had Idea of making one-to-one function as we do in (0,1) to (1,3) but I don't think that's the case, any Ideas ?

Actually, that's exactly the case! I suggest you proceed as follows:

1. Write, rigorously and thoroughly, how you would prove that $|(0,1)|=|(1,3)|$
2. Try and follow how you prove (1), and see what happens of $(1,3)$ is, instead, $(a, 3)$ for some general $a<3$.
3. Try and follow how you prove (2), and see what happens if $(a, 3)$ is, instead, $(a,b)$ for some general $b>a$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, define $f:(0,1)\to (a,b)$ and $g:(a,b)\to (0,1)$ with
$$f(x) = a(1-x) + bx \quad\mbox{and}\quad g(y) = \frac{y-a}{b-a}. $$
Verify that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of one another.

---

More generally, one can readily obtain a bijection $(a,b) \to (c,d)$ from the above via composition $(a,b)\to (0,1) \to (c,d)$.

**Further remark**. Cantor-Bernstein is not necessary here. It is sufficient to give a bijection. The power of CBT appears when one has to prove $(a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ have same cardinality, for instance. It is sufficient to find injective maps $(a,b)\to (a,b]$ and $(a,b]\to (a,b)$. Giving an explicit bijection is not so straightforward (but not too difficult, either).

Comment: And that's similar to finding a function between (1,3) because its one-to-one. and since you found one-to-one from (0,1) to (a,b) and (a,b) to (0,1) by Cantor-Bernstein theory the cardinality is equal right?

Comment: @Ivan By definition, cardinalities are equal if there exists a bijection between the sets. Cantor-Bernstein(-Schroeder) is not necessary here. Yes, a bijection $(0,1)\to (1,3)$ can be found using the maps I showed.

Comment: Thank you all , helped me a lot.